# Probabilities for some substring of a multinomial trial?

Tags: probability

Given a multinoulli distribution of categories $(C_1,C_2,...,C_n)$ with associated probabilities $\left\{p_1,p_2,\ldots ,p_n\right\}$ with $\sum _{i=1}^n p_i=1$, one uses the multinomial distribution to derive probabilities of possible outcomes.

My question is: is there a generalized method to apply the same to some substring of the total string of trials, that is, for a sequence of $N$ multinoulli trials, if one wishes to get the probability that some length $M$ substring of the $N$ trials, $M<=N$, has some outcome?

Concretely, say the distribution is on three categories with probabilities $\left\{p_1,p_2,p_3\right\}$ and 100 trials are made. I might want to ask "What is the probability there is a consecutive sequence of 10 trials among the 100 where there are more than 5 of category 1 and no category 3?"

Comment: This might be overkill, but the Goulden-Jackson cluster method should work; it counts words over an alphabet which avoid some forbidden subwords, and it can take the probabilities into account. I'll try it later today if no solution is posted.

Comment: @tad - I thought about that (based on your other answers using the method that were most effective and appreciated), but it seemed it might be a bit messy to set up.

Comment: It is certainly messy. The number $d$ of minimal "bad" subwords (in the sense that arises in the GJCM)  is on the order of $n^M$ in bad cases (for example, if one of your constraints is "no 3's" then all minimal bad subwords have length $M$.) And you have to solve a linear system over $\mathbb{Q}$ of dimension $d$. This is a pain but the complexity doesn't depend on $N$.  In contrast, a naive inclusion-exclusion approach would (I think) be exponential in $N$.